# Plugin Development - Embedding Custom Framework to XPC

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I have recently created a custom framework that is planned to be re-used for multiple projects. The catch is, this is for a plugin, and knowing that we can't simply embed the framework within the plugin's bundle, due to symbol collisions and what-not, I'm thinking of simply embedding it with the plugin's XPC. On a side-note, this framework will be used to launch custom interfaces, such as a view controller, views, and use some delegates slapped inside it that the plugin will have to take ownership (which I am hoping). Which brings me to my question: is it possible for a different process to take ownership of objects instantiated in the XPC? I am quite new to using frameworks, so I've spent hours trying to jerry-rig stuff together in XCode based on tutorials I've found online, sadly to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *framework* is a bundle of code and resources that can be used, and reused, by multiple applications. It can be embedded within your application, be part of the operating system (the entirety of Cocoa is actually a collection of frameworks), or dynamically located and programmatically loaded at runtime. Once loaded, the framework's code, classes, and resources appear to the application as if they had been compiled directly into the host app. The key is that the code executes directly, in your process's memory space.

*XPC* is an **inter-process** communications facility. It allows one process to send and receive messages with a different process. It cannot be used to communicate with itself.

You cannot "take ownership" of an object using XPC. All XPC messages serialize ("archive" in Cocoa-speak) any object and de-serialize that object on the receiving end. The second process now how a replica of the original object; it is not a reference to the original object and is constrained to the boundaries of its process.

If your second process needs to display something, you have (basically) three options:

(1) Make the second process its own application. The second process can be a full-fledged Cocoa app with windows and so forth. You can make it an "accessory" app, so it does not have a menubar or appear in the dock. See `LSUIPresentationMode` Info.plist property and/or `NSApplication.activationPolicy`.

(2) The advanced technique is to use an `IOSurface`. An `IOSurface` is, essentially, a method by which a second process (your XPC Service) can draw directly into a window of your application. Again, the drawing objects still exist—and are completely isolated in—the second process; but what they draw will appear in your application as if they were local view objects. (This is how Safari works; every browser page is rendered by an isolated background process drawing into a surface.)

(3) Use a poor-man's `IOSurface`: send your data to the second process, have it render the results into something (pixel array, TIFF, PNG, ...) that can be serialized and drawn by the host app, then use XPC to send that rendered image back to the host app for display.

[Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html)

[IOSurface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iosurface)

Comment: Hi, James. Thanks for the sweet information! Just wanted to clarify: what I want is the plugin, through the host app., to be calling the plugin's XPC to instantiate objects for the former to take ownership. Perhaps I should have worded it better. Regardless, is this possible? Though that would mean the plugin target either needs to have a copy of the framework in its bundle, or maybe make set its framework search paths to the XPC's /Frameworks product path (just a shot in the dark here).

Comment: The problem I'm having is the use of the term "plug-in". A plug-in could contain a framework or library (which runs in the local process) or it could be a helper (runs in a separate process). Since you say you're calling the "plug-in's XPC" I'm going to assume the latter.

Comment: XPC rules: (1) All objects sent from one process to another must be serialized (archived) and de-serialized at the other end. (2) Because of (1), the code that defines those classes must exist in both processes. (3) All objects sent via XPC must support secure coding. So, conceptually, it's as if your objects in process A get archived and are written to a file, then process B reads that file and reconstructs those same objects. That's as close as they get. If that's what you mean by "take ownership", then you're good. If you need something else, please explain.